# WxPython: Create Resizable Columns

Tags: python, wxpython

I just recently started using `Wxpython` and I am coding something for a friend that requires a `UI` that has **adjustable columns** (you can change the width).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wx.ListCtrl](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxListCtrl)